# Local variable output is not being shown

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run a simple program:

```
class Pras
  def samleMethod
    a = 12
    p "a"
  end
end
```

There are no errors, but why is not output being shown?

#### Edit

```
class Pras
  def samleMethod
    a = 12
    p a
  end
end
```

Comment: I would suggest to read some underlying references and tutorials, and ask the community for help in more complicated situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Pras
  def samleMethod
    a = 12
    p a
  end
end
```

In this you are creating a class named Pras with public method named sampleMethod.

I assume you have some knowledge with OOP

so when ever you are accessing a a method you need to create an instance of class to access it.

```
p =  Pras.new
```

Now you can access the method using the instance

```
p.sampleMethod
```

or both in one line as

```
  Pras.new.sampleMethod
```

I would suggest you to have a through look at this tuts. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_quick_guide.htm

methods will not be executed unless they are called.

Try this code online [here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/236cf)

---

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the string 'a' rather than the variable. Use this instead: `p a`

Edit:

As Rostyslav mentioned, you are not executing anything: Try `Pras.new.samleMethod`

Comment: Do you instantiate your class and calling samleMethod?

Comment: Thaks i tried the way you mentioned , please see the edited question , but still there is any output.

Comment: I dont know how to do that , please tell me how to get the Output printed in above program ??

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me:

Here we define class:

```
irb(main):014:0> class Pras
irb(main):015:1> def samleMethod
irb(main):016:2> a = 12
irb(main):017:2> p a
irb(main):018:2> end
irb(main):019:1> end
=> nil
```

Here's how to create and instance object of that class and call instance method with actually do printing:

```
irb(main):020:0> Pras.new.samleMethod
12
=> 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked . But i have  a question why it isn't working this way ??  new Pras.samleMethod() (Java Style)

Comment: @PreethiJain Because Ruby is not Java; they have different syntax.